# os.path.realpath(__file__) does not return the expected path

Tags: python, macos, environment

I run my script like:

```
python3 tools/debug_tool.py
```

I print `__file__` inside script, it's ok:

```
tools/debug_tool.py
```

But `os.path.realpath(__file__)` is wrong:

`/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Resources/tools/debug_tool.py`

Same result for `os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Why this happens?

Expected result of `os.path.realpath(__file__)` is something like:

```
/Users/my_user/my_project/tools/debug_tool.py
```

Also when I save file in current directory, like `cv2.imwrite('temp.png', image)` it also save file to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Resources/`

For some reason `os.getcwd()`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Resources
```

Comment: What do you mean _is wrong_?

Comment: It should be absolute path to `tools/debug_tool.py`, like `/Users/my_user/my_project/tools/debug_tool.py` but instead it's some weird python path with appended `tools/debug_tool.py`

Comment: Is `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Resources/tools/debug_tool.py` a real file that exists on your computer?  Is it the same file as your script, or a different file with different contents?

Comment: It sounds like your working directory might have been changed.

Comment: @JohnZwinck No, it's not a real file, however directory `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/Resources` exist.

Comment: Yeah, your working directory got changed. Are you *actually* running your script as `python tools/debug_tool.py`, as in actually typing that line into a shell prompt and hitting Enter, or are you running it through an IDE or something?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I'm running it in console.

Comment: Run `pwd` and `realpath $PWD` in the shell and see what those give. Maybe you have a symlink you didn't know about, or you're not where you think you are.

Comment: `pwd` and `realpath $PWD` gives me correct project dir.

Answer (score 0):

[`os.path.realpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) is supposed to resolve symbolic links and return the canonical path:

> Return the canonical path of the specified filename, eliminating any
>   symbolic links encountered in the path (if they are supported by the
>   operating system).

Note that you also need resolve the directory of the file:

```
os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

---

If you are looking for the absolute path without resolving symbolic links, you need to use [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most
>   platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as
>   follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

should generate the required output:

```
/Users/my_user/my_project/tools/debug_tool.py
```

---

In case that none of the above works then it means that your current working directory is different to the one that you thought. For example, if you are using an IDE, it might be worth checking your current working directory:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: `dirname` isn't going to help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce -- works for me. You didn't post the actual code you're running. I created a file named *tmp/d.py* relative to `$HOME` with the following content:

```
import os
print("__file__: " + __file__)
print("realpath: " + os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Running it with the Homebrew installed python3, `/usr/local/bin/python3 tmp/d.py`, produces the expected output:

```
__file__: tmp/d.py
realpath: /Users/krader/tmp/d.py
```

If that doesn't produce the same output on your system something is seriously broken :-) But I suspect you haven't accurately described the problem.

Comment: Yes, it should work, but in my case something in environment is broken, i.e. working directory is broken, so the question now is more like how to fix broken working directory.

Comment: @mrgloom, What happens if you do exactly what I did?